# Issue with subprocess.Popen and executing ssh command

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I am using subprocess.Popen to execute an OS command. Here is what I am trying to emulate in my code:

```
ssh -T myhost < /path/to/some/file
```

It works fine like this:

```
def runWorkerCode(filer, filename):
    command = "/usr/bin/ssh -T " + filer + " < /devel/myscript"
    try:
        p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        out, _ = p.communicate()
    except Exception:
        print "Error: %s" % Exception
        sys.exit(1)
    return out.rstrip().split('\n')
```

But the following calls to Popen do not work:

```
        p = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/ssh", "-T", filer, "<", "/devel/myscript"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        p = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/ssh -T", filer, "< /devel/myscript"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

I tried a few other combinations but only method I can get to work is defining the command variable and only providing it to `Popen()`. I've also tried `shell=False`.

The first method works but the latter approach seems "cleaner" to me.

Why doesn't `Popen` allow me to specify the arguments in a list?

Comment: This will run on Linux and Solaris (both sparc and x86) hosts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `shell=True` on UNIX, you should provide your arguments as a string. When you provide a list, `subprocess` interprets the first item in the list as your entire command string, and the rest of the items in the list as arguments passed to the shell itself, rather than your command. So in your example above, you're ending up with something like this:

```
/bin/sh -T filer < /dev/myscript -c "/usr/sbin/ssh"
```

Definitely not what you meant!

Conversely, when you use `shell=False`, you can only pass a string if you're running a single command with no arguments. If you do have arguments, have to pass the comamnd as a sequence. You also can't use shell redirection via the `<` character, because there is no shell involved.

If you want to use `shell=False`, you can use the `stdin` keyword argument to pass a file handle to `/dev/myscript`:

```
 f = open("/dev/myscript")
 p = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/ssh", "-T", filer], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=f, shell=False)
```

The rules for when to pass a string vs. when to pass a sequence are pretty confusing, especially when you bring Windows into the mix as well. I would read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) carefully to try to understand it all. Check out both the section on `args` and the section on `shell`.

Comment: That's not what the docs say, "args is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence of program arguments. Providing a sequence of arguments is generally preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file names). **If passing a single string, either shell must be ```True``` (see below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed without specifying any arguments.**"

Comment: @wnnmaw I think this is more relevant *"On Unix with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh. If args is a string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell. This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be when typed at the shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or backslash escaping filenames with spaces in them. **If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself.**"*. Since it suggests you *can* pass a sequence with `shell=True`.

Comment: @wnnmaw However, the docs also say this: "If shell is True, it is recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence." I'll edit my answer to try to clarify things.

Comment: @wnnmaw Actually, now that I read it again, it's saying that if you provide a sequence with `shell=True`, the first element is the command string, and the rest are arguments passed **to the shell**. So you really should be passing a string if `shell=True` unless you want to pass arguments to `/bin/sh`